# Using Jenkins for Continuous Deployment of WebApp - Publish Artifacts to Server

Tags: jenkins, continuous-deployment

We are searching for a CI and CD Solution for our WebApp based on NodeJS/Meteor.

Our Process should be:

- On each Push to Master/ Pull Request/ Merge to Master do the following:
- Checkout
- Run Code Style Checks (coffeelint, scsslinter, etc.)
- Build Code
- Run Tests
- Generate Tarball-Archive
- Deploy archive to Developmet (Quality Management) Server, extract and run

next step would be manual testing of the app on our dev server.

when we think it is deployable, I want have a button in jenkins like "Deploy these Artifacts NOW to Live-Instance". How can I achive this? Also Nice would be something like deploy these artifacts at 2am to the live instances.

***From Checkout to deploy to dev-server is already implemented in jenkins. What we need now is a button "deploy this artifact to live"***

Comment: Am i missing something? You just need to create a job to deploy the artifact that can be run manually, triggered by something or just scheduled.. But i think there is more behind your question...

Comment: Have you considered using Maven as build tool? That would cover the 4 steps _Run Code Style Checks_, _Build Code_, _Run Tests_, _Generate Tarball-Archive_. This Maven and the other steps can be handled by appropriate Jenkins plugins.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: "Process should be" should be "process is" then, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You need another job to get this working. The other job takes the artifact from the build job and deploy it wherever you want.

There is no possibility to include such behavior in the same job.

Comment: is there a way to chose which version I want to deploy?

Comment: That's not true, IMHO. There's the **_Post-build action_** → **_[ArtifactDeployer] - Deploy the artifacts from build workspace to remote locations_** from the [ArtifactDeployer Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ArtifactDeployer+Plugin).

Comment: You can deploy with it after build and timed?

Comment: A misunderstanding. I referred just to the bulleted list points while you referred just to the paragraph after next.